# Accessing in between entity in phoenix template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm making kind of school presence tracker but I have encountered an issue. I have two main entities User, Event and entity presence in between of them bounding them together. I'm accessing main entity in Template, but i need to access relevant in between entity to read the state (if presence state 1 green bg if 0 red)

User:

```
schema "users" do
    field :login, :string
    field :password, :string

    #stuff

    has_many :presences, Presence
    has_many :events, through: [:presences, :event]

    timestamps
  end
```

Events:

```
schema "events" do
    field :name, :string

    #Stuff

    has_many :presences, Presence, on_delete: :fetch_and_delete
    has_many :users, through: [:presences, :user]
end
```

Presence:

```
schema "presences" do
    field :state, :integer

    belongs_to :user, Kpsz.Model.User, foreign_key: :user_id
    belongs_to :event, Kpsz.Model.Event, foreign_key: :event_id

    timestamps
end
```

And my problem is that i have no idea how to access that state thing because I'm using data like this.

template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <strong>Nazwa:</strong>
        <%= @event.name %>
      </li>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="row">
    <%= for user <- @event.users do %>
      <div class="col-md-2 display-user">
        <div class="row">
          <%= user.class %>
        </div>
        <!-- i need access presence state here -->
        <div user_id="<%= user.id %>" event_id="<%= @event.id %>">
          Potwierdz
        </div>
      </div>
    <%= end %>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" id="map-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

And finally Action:

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    event = Repo.get!(Event, id) |> Repo.preload([:users])
    render(conn, "show.html", event: event)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your for comprehension to use the `presences` (which will be preloaded when preloading the users.) Each presence will contain the `user` that you require.

```
<%= for presence <- @event.presences do %>
  <div class="col-md-2 display-user">
    <div class="row">
      <%= presence.user.class %>
    </div>
    <%= presence.state %>
    <div user_id="<%= presence.user.id %>" event_id="<%= @event.id %>">
      Potwierdz
    </div>
  </div>
<%= end %>
```

Comment: ow... That's easier than i thought. Thank you very, very much. Gonna try it immediately